# Android Studio problems

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android application development.I am using android studio 1.5, Android 6 in windows 7 but I faced several problems:

1) SDK manager and AVD manager do not open from the dropdown list from tools>android> SDK manager/AVD manager. it only open from the sdk folder outside android studio.

2)while openning the SDK manager from sdk folder getting error like:
failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml reason:unknown Host dl.google.com android

3)There are No CPU/ABI system image installed for this target. I searched and found that I must installed this from SDK manager but when I open SDK manager didn't find the package.

Comment: can you post the screenshots?

Comment: yes you have problem with importing library of google play services

Comment: where are you connecting from ? Iran perhaps ?! If so use vpn or someother way to bypass sanctions which are supposed to be lifted by now, but unfortunately have not yet !